# how to add scope if I use IService in Controller and connect Iservice in order as IService->Service->IRepository->Repository

Tags: asp.net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1, irepository

This is the ApiController I want to use to get this Data.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRegionService _service;
    public TestController(IRegionService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<RegionModel> Get()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/region/getAll")]
    public IEnumerable<RegionModel> GetAll()
    {
        return _service.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Now To get this data, I go through the steps explained in the title.

```
IService->Service->IRepository->Repository
```

From `Respository` I get the data using LLBLGen.
How do I put scope to use this repository in the project? I am also using `AutoMapper` and created `Automapper.cs`.

I added to the `Automapper.cs` as below

```
CreateMap<IRegionService, RegionService>();
CreateMap<IRegionRepository, RegionRepository>();
```

and getthing this error.

> Unable to resolve service for type ' .Services.IRegionService' while attempting to activate ' .ApiController.TestController'.

Answer (score 1):

**AutoMapper** is a tool for Mapping, not for [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

You must register `IRegionService` and `IRegionRepository` into `DI` in startup class like this

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IRegionService, RegionService>();
    services.AddScoped<IRegionRepository, RegionRepository>();
}
```